# How do I use AJAX to create a list of a server-side directory?

Tags: javascript, ajax, directory, file-handling

Given how most questions I've seen regarding this concept aren't clear with their end goal, I want to start off with a bit of Python code and use that as the base of this question.

```py
from glob import glob

print(glob('*'))
```

The preceding code prints off a list of all files and/or folders it detects in a directory (`*` marking the current directory that the script is running in), with the help of the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html). So if I were to run the script within a directory with a folder and two images, the resulting output would be the following list:

```
['folder1','image1.png','image2.png','script.py']
```

What I'm looking to do is to recreate this functionality within Javascript for content local to a webserver. (To make life easy, let's say this is all running off `localhost`) From what I've managed to find, AJAX is the best modern method of Javascript file handling there is. With it, I've been able to call an `httpsRequest` to the folder I want, but the only response I've managed to get is an HTML dump of what I presume to be the server's file explorer. Trying to use modifiers such as `responseText` yield `<empty sting>` responses in the console. For context, this is the code I've currently been working with:

```js
function() {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (!httpRequest) {
        alert("Giving up :( Cannot create an XMLHTTP instance");
        return false;
    }
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = console.log(httpRequest);
    httpRequest.open('GET', '/testing/');
    httpRequest.send();
}
```

Comment: `httpRequest.onreadystatechange` needs to be set to a function that will run when the response is received. It should then print `httpRequest.responseText`.

Comment: You'll only get a directory listing if the web server is set up to provide one, and not always then. You probably don't want to do that for security reasons. The usual way to do this is to set up a server-side script that returns precisely, and only, what you want it to return, and applies whatever authentication is needed.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Thanks for the clarification on directory listings! Regarding the server-side script you mentioned, do you know of any resources that go into detail on how to set that up? It sounds like something I should be looking more into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Gotta love the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).*

### Why this doesn't work

AJAX's functionality is not designed for dynamic file handling like Python's `glob`. It's primarily designed to exchange information one file at a time, with the ability to alter that file in the `XMLHttpRequest`. This isn't a downside, as it's useful for handing config files in JSON or communicating with a PHP database. It's also worth bringing up something mentioned in Tangentially Perpendicular's comment:

> You'll only get a directory listing if the web server is set up to provide one, and not always then. [That said] you probably don't want to do that for security reasons.

### "Then how do I create a dynamic list of articles to show up in my HTML?"

And there's our X.

What you really want is a [Static Site Generator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A_l0qrPUJds). With it, you'll be able to create and compile a site that handles creating that article list for you.

*For those looking for further reading, keep in mind that SSG's are often used in reference to the* Jamstack.